# Django view not returning the json data but does so at the shell

Tags: python, django, json, httpresponse

If I startup the dev server and goto a certain view. I get no response.

my view is like the following

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from goals.models import Child
import json

def viewChildren(request):
    jsonData= []
    allChildren = Child.objects.all()
    for child in allChildren:
        jsonData.append({'id': child.id, 'name': child.name})
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(jsonData),mimetype="application/json")
```

To test out what was going on, i did a the following

```
python manage.py shell
>>> import goals.views as v
>>> r = v.viewChildren('')
>>> print r
Content-Type: application/json

[{"id": 1, "name": "Test Child"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Second child"}]
```

So I know that the view is correct and the right data *is* being passed on after the view is called... But this isn't being passed on when I view this from a browser.

Any suggestions? 
(this is similar to a lot of questions but none that I have found have shown the above situation where the view IS providing the correct response but from a browser it is not)

Comment: I have also put the proper url in the urls.py with the following: `url(r'children/$', 'goals.views.viewChildren')` and I'm trying to reach the page at `http://localhost:8080/children/`  the admin pages work just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solved the problem. I took out all of the rest of the urls as I thought maybe they weren't correct. Turns out that a previous edit had made all urls goto a blank index one which returned no response. After fixing that, the above worked just fine.

Thanks for looking anyways...

Comment: I think you could accecpt the answer